# What's the shortcut to navigator in XCode 4.5?

Tags: xcode4.5

[image: shortcut snapshot]

I'm thinking what's the shortcut to to this ? I don't know the exact name to this in XCode. thus I can't bind my key shortcut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "Show Document Items".

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

Under "Key Bindings" is listed as "Standard Editor > Show Documented Items"
or from menu: "View" -> "Standard Editor" -> "Show Documented Items".